# SSH passthrough?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, port-forwarding, qemu

I borrow the word "passthrough" from GPU passthrough in virtual machine because the concepts sound similar to me, at least from usage point of view. Here I have a QEMU MV, both host and guest being ubuntu 20.04. I use port forwarding to ssh from host into guest:

```
ssh localhost -p5555
```

Now I have a second host, also running ubuntu 20.04. Suppose the hostname of the machine containing QEMU MV is `host1`, while the hostname of the second host is `host2`. `host2` can ssh into `host1` using normal ssh command. My question is: how to use a single ssh command to connect `host2` to the guest OS? Assume the user names are all the same on `host1`,`host2` and guest: `myname`. Since under port forwarding, `host1` uses `localhost` to specify the guest VM, not its hostname, so I don't know how to write the ssh command.

I tried `ssh myname@host1 -p5555` on `host2` but `ssh` does not return. Instead, it behaves like a command-line editor. The guest is on. So, what option can I use to let a single ssh command to connect from `host2` into the guest OS? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain to do is `host2 -> host1 -> localhost:5555`.

The [`-J`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1#J) option allows easily to do this from host2 using the [`-J`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1#J) / [`ProxyJump`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#ProxyJump) feature:

> `-J` *destination*
>
> Connect to the target host by first making a `ssh` connection to the
> jump host described by destination and then establishing a TCP
> forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.
>
> [...]

So without yet considering the option for port 5555:

```
ssh -J host1 localhost
```

Also as documented [right after](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1#J)...

> Note that **configuration directives supplied on the command-line
> generally apply to the destination host and not any specified jump
> hosts**. Use `~/.ssh/config` to specify configuration for jump hosts.

...extra options like specifying a port don't affect the Jump Host but will only affect the final target. Just add back the port option:

```
ssh -p 5555 -J host1 localhost
```

You could even have different users on all 3 systems and specify the user names in the command:

```
ssh -p 5555 -J myhost1user@host1 myvmuser@localhost
```

Note: Each ssh server requires its own separate authentication. If you don't use features to avoid having to provide passwords like by using ssh keys, you will probably be asked twice in a row a password: once for connecting to host1, once for connecting to the VM behind localhost:5555.